# is this ok to use an array's key with whitespaces

Tags: php, arrays, string

I am trying to parse a csv file using `fgetcsv()` function but the CSV file's heading consists value like `E-mail Address'` which I need to convert as an array's key but I am wondering if it's OK to use a non-standard name for a key?

I would be saving this value in database directly so I am not sure if getting a value like this `$entry['E-mail Address']` would be ok

Comment: I don't think it's ideal, but it should work. Did you try it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A string is a string. The fact that it has a whitespace in the middle shouldn't prevent you from using it as an array's key.

Comment: What I am worried about is that I may have get two or more spaces while getting that file so in that case I need to have something to prevent it don't I?